# No. of solutions of $f(x)=f'(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be a fixed continuous function such that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)$. Then the equation $f(x)=f'(x)$ admits
>
> 1. No solution $x \in (0,1)$
> 2. More than one solution $x \in (0,1)$
> 3. Exactly one solution $x \in (0,1)$
> 4. At least one solution $x \in (0,1)$

As I have tried taking $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$ ruled out options 1 and 2 and by Rolle's Theorem there exists $c\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.  Then I thought to construct function $g(x)=f(x)-f'(x)$ to check zeros but I'm stuck because $f'(x)$ need to be continuous.

Can anyone give some hint to proceed further?

Comment: Don't you mean you've ruled out 1 and 3?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The problem is to find all $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)$, which is very different from finding functions such that $f(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x$. As stated, $f$ is *given*.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, that makes more sense than my initial reading.

Comment: yeah sorry ruled out 1. and 3.

Comment: Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$, what is $g'(x)$?

Comment: You have received two answers to your old question, please don't change the question. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can guarantee any of the choices. Below are three possibilities for $f(x)$ which have

1. $0$ solutions, 2. $1$ solution, 3. $\infty$ solutions.

---

1. $f(x)=4$
2. $f(x)=(x-\frac12)^2$
3. $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 2):

1. **No solution $x\in(0,1)$.** Yes, this can happen.
   Consider the constant polynomial $p(x)=5$. We have $p(0)=p(1)=5$ and $p(x)\neq p^\prime(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.
2. **More than one solution $x\in(0,1)$.** Yes, this can happen. Build a polynomial function $p(x)$, with degree $8$,  whose roots are $r_1=0$, $r_2=r_3=0.25$,  $r_4=r_5=0.50$, $r_6=r_7=0.75$ and $r_8=1$. Then $p(r_2)=p^\prime(r_2)=0$, $p(r_4)=p^\prime(r_4)=0$ and $p(r_6)=p^\prime(r_6)=0$. Use [Vieta's formulas.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas)
3. **Exactly one solution $x\in(0,1)$.** Consider $p(x)=x^2-x$. We have $p(0)=p(1)=0$ and $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$  root of $p(x)=p^\prime(x)$. As pointed out by **lisyarus**.
4. **At least one solution  $x\in(0,1)$ .** From the first example given above, this statement is not true.